# How to make a firebase cloud onUpdate function to work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have adding and outputing comments in appliction.

That should work in realy time.

In my Comments component where which is statful component I have entire logic for geting data and saving in the firebase.

Now I want here to add a onUpdate fb cloud function.

I tried on next way and does not work:

```
const onCommentsAdded = this.runtime.fb.ref('/comments').onUpdate((change) => {
  const after = change.after;
  console.log('This is after: ', after, change.after)
})
```

Application cannot be compiled, **this is error**:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): runtime.fb.ref(...).onUpdate is not a
>   function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're looking at the `Realtime Database` on Firebase and not Firestore.

The library you are trying to access doesn't look correct. See the [Database Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) documentation.

```
const onCommentsAdded = functions.database.ref('/comments')
  .onUpdate((change, _context) => {
    const after = change.after;
    console.log('This is after: ', after, change.after)
   });
```

Try updating the function to use `functions.database.ref` instead of `this.runtime.fb.ref`

Comment: I tried and get the error: http://prntscr.com/l1ai09
Maybe I need to move that code in componentDidMount or someone else?

Comment: Are you trying to run cloud functions? Why are they sitting in your components? They usually sit in a `functions` folder. See an example here; https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/child-count